# Match the number within a text jquery

Tags: jquery, regex

I'm trying to match only text ID within the class "example". I'm able to return it with nodeType, but I just want the ID in this case.

```
<ul class="account">
<li class="example">My ID: 4558102</li>
</ul>

$(document).ready(function() {
    var myid = $('.example').contents().filter(function() {
        return this.nodeType
    }).text();
alert(myid)
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/M28sA/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can  remove non numeric characters using `replace(/\D/g,'')`.Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var myid = $('.example').contents().filter(function() {
        return this.nodeType;
    }).text().replace(/\D/g,'');
    alert(myid);
});
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/M28sA/1/)**

Comment: Thank you. This will be very useful for me knowing this missing piece.

Answer (score 2):

You can try with:

```
var myid = +$('.example').text().match(/\d+$/)[0];
```